# XNA Differences between Initialize and LoadContent

Tags: c#, xna, initialization, sprite

What differences are there between Initialize and LoadContent? I have tried to brake the XNA game by moving things from LoadContent to Initialize and back but as long as you call things the appropriate way everything works no matter where I put it.

Comment: i meant that if I want to load an image, sound or have something equal a number befor the game starts I can do it in either LodeContent, or Initialize. I just looked at what I had put as an example, I will change it to look more accurate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation for `LoadContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.loadcontent%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) states that

> This method is called by Initialize

The [documentation for `Initialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.initialize%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) states

> In classes that derive from Game, you need to call base.Initialize in Initialize, which  will automatically enumerate through any game components that have been added to Game.Components and call their Initialize methods.

So the base initialize method will initialize game components before any content is loaded, the LoadContent method ensures that your resources are loaded at the appropriate time.

Comment: But what's so confusing is WHEN exactly loadcontent gets called. If you put code after base.initialize() you will find that loadcontent also has been called already. But the documentation for "Initialize" does not mention that this function also calls LoadContent....

Answer (score 2):

`Game.Run()` (see your *Program.cs*, i.e. `game.Run()`) is the method that runs:

1) `Game.Initialize()` (Which calls `Game1.Initialize()` and the initial `Game1.LoadContent()`).

2) `Game.BeginRun()` (which calls `Update()`, `Draw()` and subsequent `LoadContent()`/`UnloadContent()` (generally speaking).

[MSDN - Game Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game_members.aspx)

**In other words, *initial* `LoadContent()` statements *can* be put into `Initialize()`, but the problem is when you want to load, reload or unload things *after* initialization is done.**

In short: Keep all your loaded content in `LoadContent()`, to avoid confusion.